# Items in ScrollView or NestedScrollView jump focus two at a time

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, vertical-scrolling, android-nestedscrollview

I'm building an Android TV app. I have a layout like so:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:transitionGroup="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:transitionGroup="false">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu 1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu 2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

        .
        .
        .

        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu 9"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

     </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It looks like this on the TV:

[image]

Now, I notice the following behavior:

If I only have enough menu items such that they fit within the screen, the key press from the remote changes the focus from one menu item to the next one correctly. However, if I add too many items, such that the layout overflows, **the focus jumps two at a time**.

I have verified that it is not because of a KeyDown followed by a KeyUp event. The initial KeyDown itself causes the jump twice.

I also tried using NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView, and got the same result.

I'm attaching GIFs of correct and incorrect behavior below:

Correct behavior:

[image]

Incorrect Behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make a new NewScrollView and extends ScrollView and Override methed executeKeyEvent();

like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGEJx.png)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.FocusFinder;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

/**
 * created by: wuzf
 * date: 2019/05/08
 * email: wuzf1234@gmail.com
 */
public class NewScrollView extends ScrollView {
public NewScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NewScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NewScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public NewScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
  defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
//        return super.executeKeyEvent(event);
    if (isFocused() && event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        View currentFocused = findFocus();
        if (currentFocused == this) currentFocused = null;
        View nextFocused = FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(this,
                currentFocused, View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        return nextFocused != null
                && nextFocused != this
                && nextFocused.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```